# Changing data in mongoose document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database, nosql

I am new to mongoose mongodb, and am trying to update data stored. I have tried the example in the api here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate but don't seem to be doing it right. It says to query for data and update it, I can do:

```
Model.findOne({ name: 'borne' }, function (err, doc) 
{
  if (err) ..
  doc.name = 'jason borne';
  doc.save(callback);
});
```

I am doing this:

```
user.find({ 'username': Username, 'code': Key}, function(err, check){
    var callback5;
    if((String(check)) === "")
    {
        res.json('nope');
    }
    else
    {
        banned: true;
        user.save(callback5);
        res.json('yep');
    }
})
```

It returns the resulting query data, but when I add the code to update the value of the boolean "banned", I get an error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming that the `user` variable is a Model object, and that what you're trying to achieve is to find a single user with a given username and code, and set the banned property of that user to be true.

The first thing is that `user.find` will return an array of users, not just a single user, so you'll want to use `user.findOne` instead.

```
user.findOne({ username: Username, code: Key}, function(err, userDoc) {
    if (err)
    {
        // TODO: Handle the error!
    }
    if (! userDoc)
    {
        res.json('nope');
    }
    else
    {
        userDoc.banned = true;
        userDoc.save(function (err) {
            if (err)
            {
                // TODO: Handle the error!
            }
            res.json('yep');
        });
    }
})
```

This queries the database for a single document that matches the username and code. If `userDoc` is null, then `res.json('nope')` will happen.

The code then sets the `banned` property of `userDoc` to be true, and then save the document back to the database. Because the `save` function is asynchronous, you want to put the `res.json('yep')` code in the callback, otherwise you won't know whether it actually happened or not.

I haven't put any actual error handling code in, I've left that for you to do, but you should always deal with any potential errors when using the standard callback pattern.

---

You could also achieve this using `findOneAndUpdate`:

```
var conditions = { username: Username, code: Key };
var update = { banned: true };
user.findOneAndUpdate(conditions, update, function (err)
{
  if (err)
  {
      res.json('nope');
  }
  else
  {
      res.json('yep');
  }
})
```